# Передать в функцию массив

Tags: javascript, массивы

Нужно передать в функцию массив чисел и для каждого значения массива выдать alert с его значением, к примеру `var someArray = newArray[12, 'str', 234, true]`, при вводе `someArray[1]` - с помощью alert будет выводиться сообщение со значением `str`.
Функция все время выдает `undefined`, нашел причину: в функцию не передается массив, она его не видит. Проверил несколькими способами, чтобы `alert` выдал значения каждого массива, но сталкиваюсь с `undefined`. Подскажите, что делаю не так.

Comment: Ужасы какие)) Наверное называть массив точно также, как имя функции - не самая хорошая идея. А вообще, в функцию массив вы передаете только во втором примере. В других примерах колбасня какая-то

Comment: согласен) но во втором примере если я передаю массив значений, alert выдает только первое из них

Comment: Может, переопределить прототип конструктора Array, чтобы он вместо каждого элемента ставил ф-ю, выводящую этот элемент? (очень, очень плохая практика переопределять прототипы стандартных объектов!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var someArray = [12, 'str', 234, true];


function changeArray(arr) {
    for( i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        alert(arr[i]);
    }
}

changeArray(someArray);
```

Не знаю как комментировать, честно.

**UPD.**
Динамически вызов

```js
submitBtn.onclick = function() {
 var someArray = [];
 var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
 
 for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
  someArray.push(inputs[i].value);  
 }
 
 changeArray(someArray);
}



function changeArray(arr) {
    for( i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  alert(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test" value="" />
<input type="text" class="test" value="" />
<input type="text" class="test" value="" />
<input type="text" class="test" value="" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="submit"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L4oav1nn/

Comment: я хотел немного другое уточнить, нужно чтобы функция работала при вводе произвольного массива в виде changeArray[1, 2, 3], или changeArray[1, 'str', false] к примеру. чтобы я не задавал var с ранее определенными значениями

Comment: @Веня У меня он забит статикой, чтоб показать, что функция работает. А так - никто не мешает вам в эту функцию передать массив данных динамически.

Comment: @Веня Попробовал добавить пример динамического вызова функции.

Comment: да спасибо, работает. я попробовал еще так сделать, не знаю на сколько это нормально: 
function changeArray() {
var newArray = [];
for ( i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
alert( arguments[i] );
}
}
вроде тоже работает. ну в принципе это тоже что и вы указали) спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Подойдет?

```js
function alertArray(arr) {
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    alert(arr[i]);
  }
}

var someArray = [12, 'str', 234, true];
alertArray(someArray);
```

Comment: даа, так код работает, я уже пробовал. хочу немного иначе, вот к примеру значения в функцию мы обычно вводим так (на примере вашей функции) alertArray(значение, значение) и с ним работает функция. хотелось бы таким же способом вводить произвольный массив и чтобы функция воспринимала его как массив. без присвоения заранее предопределенных значений в var

Comment: @Веня можете вызывать и так: `alertArray( [12, 'str', 234, true] );`

Answer (score 0):

Можно так, красиво-лаконично:

```js
[12, 'str', 234, true].map(alert);
```

Метод объекта Array [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) применит функцию, указанную его аргументом, к каждому элементу массива. В эту функцию первым параметром передаётся значение очередного элемента массива, вторым - его индекс, и третьим – весь массив.

Так – то же, чуть более длинно:

```
[12, 'str', 234, true].map( function(v){ alert(v);} );
```